# Pentadactyl: Use current tab's url in command

Tags: pentadactyl

I would like to create a mapping for emailing a link to the page displayed in the current tab:

```
:map ,m :! mail -s "here's a link" email@example.com<cr><current-url><C-d>
```

I am trying to figure out how to replace  with the url of the page currently displayed in the tab.

If you are familiar with vim, it would be the equivalent of %.

Comment: Don't worry about the details of the mail command. For instance, <C-d> might not actually work in  my mapping. I am solely interested in how to access the tab's url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:execute`, where you can use the Javascript API:

```
:map ,m :execute '!echo ' + buffer.URL + ' | mail -s "Subject" mail@example.com'
```

Or use a javascript mapping, like:

```
javascript <<EOF
function MyFoo() {
    alert(buffer.URL.host);
}
EOF
map <Leader>f -js MyFoo();
```

See https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/blob/master/pentadactylrc#L212 for a more sophisticated function to setup the editor based on host names.

Comment: how do I adapt this if I want to open current page in another browser eg chromium ? I tried the obvious : execute ' !echo ' + buffer.URL + ' | chromium' but it doesn't work.

Comment: got it working with javascript io.run("chromium", [buffer.URL])

Comment: @Niels: alternatively, you could just replace `!echo` with `!chromium` in the `:execute` statement above.