# pentadactyl - syntactic sugar for command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, alias, pentadactyl

On [Pentadactyl: Use current tab's url in command](https://superuser.com/questions/708927/pentadactyl-use-current-tabs-url-in-command/716167) I learned how to create a command that uses the current buffer's URL.  I'm using this to rewrite the URL to use the [hypothes.is](http://hypothes.is) "via hypothesis" proxy:

```
map -builtin <C-x><C-V> :execute ':open http://via.hypothes.is/' + buffer.URL
```

But when I press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-V</kbd> I see the whole command printed out in the "echo area":

```
:execute ':open http://via.hypothes.is/' + buffer.URL
```

Is there a way to make that print out more briefly, so that that whole command has an "alias" like `:via`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### defining an alias

The simplest way would be to *give* the command an alias and map the keybinding to invoke that alias.

```
command! via :execute ':open http://via.hypothes.is/' + buffer.URL
map -b <C-x><C-V> :via
```

You can then execute the command either with the keybinding, or on the command line via its alias `via`.

### executing the command immediately

That said, do you actually need the command to print out on the command line and wait for you to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>? A preferable solution would be to just have the command execute immediately when you execute the keybinding. You can do that by either:

1. adding `<CR>` to the end of the command you execute

   ```
   map <C-x><C-v> :via<CR>
   ```

   (this solution is portable to Vimperator); or
2. using the `-ex` option to the `map` command.

   ```
   map <C-x><C-v> -ex via
   ```

### executing command and printing a message

If for some reason you don't want an actual alias, but just want the command to execute while printing "via" in the echo area, you could use a binding like this:

```
map <C-x><C-V> -js 
\ dactyl.open('http://via.hypothes.is/' + buffer.URL);
\ commandline.echo('via',commandline.HL_INFOMSG);
\ setTimeout(function(){ commandline.echo('', commandline.HL_INFOMSG); }, 500);
```

The `500` at the end is the delay (in milliseconds) before the message disappears. If you want it the message to stay until you enter a new command or change tabs, just remove the last line entirely.

Comment: @Joe Corneli: thanks for pointing out the missing keystrokes in the `map` commands of the second section. Not sure why your edit was rejected, but I've fixed the commands, anyway.